# Negative amounts from source workbook are appearing in brackets but I want to see the values from source to Taregt as is

Tags: excel, vba

I have one Macro code from which the source negative AMOUNTs are displayed in brackets () in Target sheet. I want to change the code to see the AMOUNT values as is from source.

Code for your reference - I am new to macro, so I dont understand where to change?

```
rngRef.Cells(nRowCount, sheetColName.Item("Amount")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                rngRef.Cells(nRowCount, sheetColName.Item("Amount")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                nRowCount = nRowCount + 1
            End If
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `Paste:=xlPasteValues` is telling to do the special paste operation of the final answer, rather than the formula. Just remove it and it should work, if I correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you josh for your quick reply. I have changed the code as below but t s throwing compilation error in second line.                                                                                           rngRef.Cells(nRowCount, sheetColName.Item("Amount")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
rngRef.Cells(nRowCount, sheetColName.Item("Amount")).Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Hanumatha. Just so you know, you can make your code more readable by using the ACCENT GRAVE (`)  character before and after

Comment: It looks like you took out too much! Just drop the expression I mentioned

Comment: Hi Josh,
I have changed the code as below(Removed, `Paste:=xlPasteValues`) though I see the values in brackets (Ex-(100)) instead with negative symbol (-100)

`rngRef.Cells(nRowCount, sheetColName.Item("Amount")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
 rngRef.Cells(nRowCount, sheetColName.Item("Amount")).PasteSpecial`

Comment: Could someone help me here.